# Spring Test: Create Few Classes Inside Test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I have an interface without implementation classes.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String getName();
}
```

And I have another class which have `MyInterface` as dependency.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyInterface implementation;
    
    public MyInterface someMethod(List<MyInterface> list){
        //logic
    }
}
```

I have to test `SomeClass`, but I don't have `MyInterface` implementation classes. Is it possible to create in test few `MyInterface` implementation classes and add them to `ApplicationContext` when I can get them as `spring beans` with `@Autowired`?

Comment: That doesn’t bring anything - interface is an abstraction, you never test an interface you always test the implementations. What is the point of creating something in test just to make tests pass? Unless it is a functional interface where you can get away with lambdas which with getName doesn’t make sense

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use JUnit 5, this is possible using `@TestConfiguration` and provide an implementation there:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private MyInterface myInterface;

  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyInterface myInterface() {
      
      /**
       * Long version of implementing your interface:
       * 
       *    return new MyInterface() {
       *         @Override
       *         public String getName() {
       *           return null;
       *         }
       *       }; 
       */
      
      // shorter ;-)
      return () -> "Hello World!";
    }
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    SomeService someService = new SomeService(myInterface);
    System.out.println(someService.doFoo());
  }

}
```

But you could also use Mockito and create a mock for your `MyInterface` and have a fast unit test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private MyInterface myInterface;

  @InjectMocks
  private SomeService someService;

  @Test
  void test() {
    when(myInterface.getName()).thenReturn("Test");
    System.out.println(someService.doFoo());
  }

}
```

While the code above technically answers what you asked for, always consider, as J Asgarov mentioned in the comments, if it makes sense to do it in this way.